# Grouping multiple files on second monitor in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want to display several files on my second monitor for reference, but I've got enough that I want to have them in a single "floating window" and and be able to select them via tabs, as you would normally do in the main IDE window. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax.aspx),

> You can dock multiple tool and document windows together in a “raft” and then move them as a unit anywhere on the desktop or to another monitor.

I haven't been able to figure this out. I can create many floating windows, and I can dock several windows to a separate area of the main window, but I can't move several files within a single floating window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN document to which you link is referring to Visual Studio **2012**, which improved on the basic multi-monitor support that was first introduced in version 2010. This window grouping ability is probably the most significant of those improvements.

It is unfortunately not present in Visual Studio **2010**. At least, not out of the box. It is available through a popular extension, [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef). It [massively overhauls the "Tab Well UI"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/10/document-well-2010-plus.aspx), adding floating tab wells and lots of other features.

That extension has *a lot* of features beyond tab-well-related ones. Since you're installing it anyway, I recommend trying some of them out—you might like some of them. But you can also turn off the ones you *don't* like, which I think is the most important feature of all. Once it's installed, you do all of this from the Tools -> Options dialog, under the Productivity Power Tools option.

If you're running an Express version of Visual Studio that doesn't support extensions, or you're opposed to installing any free tools that might make your life easier, you don't have many options. About the best thing you can do is to unmaximize the VS window, stretch it across your multiple monitors, and then dock the tabs in the main window. You can even use horizontal/vertical groups, if you like. It's cumbersome but it does work, just the way we used to have to do it in the versions prior to 2010.